# Send business card with Custom Form in Office Outlook

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2007, outlook-2010

I need to create a Custom business card along with custom form , and I want to send it as an attachment just like a normal business card , but receiver should be able to open it with the custom form.

Answer (score 0):

You have a VBA tag but there is no VBA solution. You cannot send live VBA to others. They would not thank you if you figured out how to do so.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/outlook-help/how-outlook-helps-protect-you-from-viruses-spam-and-phishing-HA010355583.aspx

***Protection from macro viruses***

*The purpose of a macro is to automate frequently used tasks. Although some macros are simply a recording of your keystrokes or mouse clicks, more powerful VBA macros are authored by developers who use code that can run many commands on your computer. For this reason, VBA macros pose a potential security risk because a hacker can introduce a malicious macro through a document that, if opened, allows the macro to run and potentially spread a virus on your computer.
In Microsoft Office 2010, the Trust Center helps to provide protection against potentially unsafe macros. In addition, Outlook blocks many potentially harmful attachments.*

In any case, if answerable, it is a SuperUser question. https://superuser.com/